# A solution is needed to run a multiple selenium test on remote sever

Tags: java, ubuntu, windows-7, selenium, winexe

For the structure, there would be three kinds of terminal.
1. Client: Client has the Firefox running on it. It will open the webpage from Web Server and trigger the test by clicking on the link on the page.

1. Web Server: Web Server runs PhP and stores all the Web Pages for triggering the test. Operating System would be Ubuntu.
2. Test Server: The test will be actually running here using selenium on java. Operating System would be Window 7. And Firefox will be opened by the test project to run check the page  needs to be checked.

What kind of methods should be used on each kind of terminal to fulfill this?

I've tried put winexe + bat file, in the web page to connect the Test Server to run the test. The bat file contains all the test case:"java xxxx" using the command line. However winexe doesn't work with windows 7. It simply wouldn't open the Firefox on Test Server.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, I define the above as follows
 **Client** : A machine where the user/service clicks a link in browser to execute the tests 
 **Webserver** : A machine where the webpages for triggering tests are present 
 **TestServer** : An arbitary machine where the test scripts are run

You can do that as following.
 Use  [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)  as a server. Include the selenium-grid plugin along with it. Create jenkins jobs so that they can trigger your tests through a batch. 
 In the test server, create a selenium-node which registers with the hub running along with jenkins.

You can access the Jenkins server jobs on an url and click on the build button so that they run on the test server

Comment: In my setups, the TestServer and Client are the same box but I think it's good to have that distinction.  I agree that Jenkins is a good way to schedule/perform tests.  It becomes especially if you expect to have multiple TestServers and use the Master/Slave feature.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. And your understanding is precise. But I'm still new to jenkins. Could you give me more details on how I should deploy jenkins with selenium-grid plugin on Webserver?

Comment: Also what does jenkins do exactly here?